# Alert Username with tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I will like to know how to alert any user username on anywebsite with tampermonkey , thank you a lot.

I tried with Shall I use get.username ? or @require *source.example.com*

Comment: It's not possible, because every website has a different way of handling usernames.

Comment: https://brainly.in/ , this site